# Using an AutoRest C# client to access a Web API with a bearer token - TokenCredentials does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, adal, bearer-token, autorest

**EDIT 10/24**
*I think this was all likely user error - see my answer below for remedy before getting too deep into this question*

**TL;DR:**
For my OAuth 2.0 code flow...

> Why does my `TokenCredentials` not work with my AutoRest client?
>   I'm getting NO bearer token applied to the request / no Authorization header set

**I know my pipeline works already..**

Using code from [this azure sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/TodoListController.cs), which is NOT an AutoRest client, I can successfully get my `access_token` and can get JSON from my protected Web API project.. so I've ruled out all the prerequisite stuff..      I know my pipeline works

**My AutoRest setup..**

1.) Downloaded from GitHub [this AutoRest repo](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) v1.1.0

2.) Downloaded my swagger JSON to disk, saved as `swagger.json`

3.) Ran this command-line to generate C# files:

`autorest --input-file=swagger.json --csharp --output-folder=MyCorp_ApiClient_Tsl --namespace='MyCorp.ApiClient' --add-credentials`

4.) Copied generated classes into my .NET 4.6.2 web site

5.) These are my NuGets:

```
- Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime version="2.3.8" 
- Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication version="2.3.1" 
- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory version="2.28.3"
```

**Here's what's not working:**

```
   AdalTokenHelper tokenHelper = new AdalTokenHelper();//helper code further below

    string token = await tokenHelper.GetTokenString();
    var svcClientCreds = new TokenCredentials(token, "Bearer");

    client = new MyCorp.ApiClient(new Uri(apiRsrcUrl), svcClientCreds, 
    new DelegatingHandler[] { new MyAzureTracingHandler() });

    //make call to OData controller...        
    MyCorp.ApiClient.Models.ODataResponseListStatus statusList = await client.Status.GetStatusAsync(expand: "StatusType",cancellationToken: defaultCancelThreadToken);

    return View(statusList.Value);
```

I've tried variations of the above, using different ctor's of `TokenCredentials`, but no matter, I can put my breakpoint in `MyAzureTracingHandler` and see the request has no Authorization headers applied.. so I get the expected `401 Unauthorized` response.

If I modify `MyAzureTracingHandler` to accept my instance of `TokenCredentials` then I can force the request to have the appropriate bearer token applied..

**This works, but, feels hack-ish:**

I changed my original client instantiation snippet from this:

```
 client = new ApiClient(new Uri(apiRsrcUrl), svcClientCreds, 
 new DelegatingHandler[] { new MyAzureTracingHandler() });
```

To this:

```
 client = new ApiClient(new Uri(apiRsrcUrl), svcClientCreds, 
 new DelegatingHandler[] { new MyAzureTracingHandler(svcClientCreds) });
```

And inside the `SendAsync` method of `MyAzureTracingHander` I do this:

```
await svcClientCreds.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

Am I doing something wrong? I don't think I should have to pass the `ServiceClientCredentials` in twice when instantiating my client.

**Appendix A - Getting access token via ADAL:**

```
    private string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
    private string tslResourceID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ross:TslWebApiResourceId"];
    private static string loginRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ross:LoginRedirectUri"];

    private AuthenticationContext authContext;
    private AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;

    public async Task<string> GetTokenString()
    {
        string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
        string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

        try
        {
            // get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
            ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

            // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's database
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, new ADALTokenCache(userObjectID));


            UserIdentifier userIdentifier = new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);

            authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(tslResourceID, clientcred, userIdentifier);
        }
        catch(AdalException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I believe I ran my `autorest` command with `--add-credentials` it's possible I may have used the older syntax... `--AddCredentials true`

I also did not run `autorest --reset` as the docs recommend you do

One of these is the culprit, because now my 1.1.0 autorest installation is generating everything correctly.

Comment: the [autorest homepage](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/) refers to the `--reset` flag.

Comment: the `--add-credentials` bit is in the 'Commonly used settings' of the [command line docs here](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/blob/master/docs/user/cli.md#user-content-commonly-used-settings)